# "Could not find application to open this link" on FireFox for Android

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-web

On clicking the "*Read this question in our app!*" link, this error pops up.

[image: screenshot]

> Couldn't find an application to open this link

If I click the Android icon in the address bar, the question opens in the app. The browser is the latest Firefox on a 2013 Moto G running Android 5.0.2.

**Update**: the link works on Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Does it show the content of the link when you hover it?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: @ott err. How do I hover on mobile?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have a 2013 Moto G.

Comment: OK, please add this to the question.

Comment: Try if a double tap works. See http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Comment: Do you have the Stack Exchange app installed? Do you have the Play Store installed?

Comment: Yes and yes. I've also noticed the link works on Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Not repro on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.83, FireFox 44.0.2, I could open the question both from the link, and the Android icon. Probably it has been fixed, could you check it on your side?

Comment: Anyway, there's a [bug report on Mozzila](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=851693) regarding this around the time OP posted this. Whether the feature was not stable, or it's not related, it's not clear.